# java 1.4 -sql server 2000:not able to insert multiple records into table

Tags: java, sql-server-2000, insert, record

INSERT INTO [UPLOAD_FILE_RECORD_FIELDS_DATA]([RECORD_ID], [FIELD_ORDER],   [FIELD_VALUE], [ERROR_CODE])

```
select ?,?,?,? 
union all 
select ?,?,?,? 
union all 
select ?,?,?,?
```

I have to insert multiple records into one table.So i am using query as below.and setting parameter values. But i am getting error code 77.What is cause?

No of records to be inserted are approx 70000.So i am inserting 100 records in one query and then using addBatch() on preparedstatment  700 times i execute whole batch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was not error code 77.it was no of updates per statement.SO Everything is working fine.